# Read facebook inbox mesaage using graph api. (Facebook SDK : 4.16.0)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am new in using facebook api for Android. I am trying to read message from facebook using Graph Api. When I try to pass **`read_mailbox`** permission I get invalid permission error.

Here is the link I tried to refer.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/user/inbox

Here is the code how I am trying to do so.

```
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_friends","email","user_about_me","read_mailbox"));
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {

GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
@Override
public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
if (response.getError() != null) {
System.out.println("ERROR" +response.getError().getErrorMessage());
} else {
System.out.println("Success");
try {
String jsonresult = String.valueOf(json);
System.out.println("JSON Result"+jsonresult);                               
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
});
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,inbox");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
}
```

Here is the link for permission which shows that read_mailbox is depricated.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions
But what is the alternative to this.
I Also wanted to send message, but I stuck here only. Any help is appriciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It says right on top of the page that you yourself referred to, _"This document refers to a feature that was removed after Graph API v2.4."_

Comment: @CBroe That's right, but my question was about alternative option. Anyways thanks for comment and downvoting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_mailbox` is deprecated and there is no alternative. It is not possible to read the user mailbox anymore.

Sending a message is easy with the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

...or the Message Dialog on Android: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#message

Comment: ok,thanks for quick response. Is it possible to send message to specific user using graph in android?

Comment: the send dialog offers a "to" parameter for this, but it is only possible for users who authorized the app too. i don´t think the message dialog offers the same, but even if: definitely only to authorized users, because else you don´t get the id.